# Grab object from MongoDB but limit number of items pulled from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My API currently has a route for Getting an event from my MongoDB database based on `event_id`. This works fine. However, I have a 'photos' array within this event object that is growing (currently over 3,000 objects within this array).
I want to pass a `limit` parameter to limit the number of results pulled from this array, but cannot figure out how. Below is my current node route and mongoDB schema:

route:

```
// get event by _id
app.get('/api/events/:event_id', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get event
    Event.findOne({object_id: req.params.event_id}, function(err, event) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        if (req.params.limit >= 0) {
            // res.jsonp(event) with photos array limited to req.params.limit
        }

        res.jsonp(event); // return event in JSON format
    });
});
```

schema:

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
event: String,
city: String,
state: String,
date: String,
start: String,
end: String,
dateState: String,
radius: String,
team_1: String,
team_2: String,
object_id: String,
longitude: String,
latitude: String,
cover: {
    img: String,
    username: String
},
photos: []
```

})

Comment: That will do it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/

Comment: Sorry for some reason it goes to the update operator :\ http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.findOne({object_id: req.params.event_id})
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function(e,doc){
        ...
});
```

### Edit

Or if you have ref on the photo... you can populate the doc array of referenced id with limit option. Hope it helps :) [All abount population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
.find(...)
.populate({
     path: 'photos',
     options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec(...)
```

#### Schema

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
event: String,
city: String,
state: String,
...
photos: [{ type:String, ref:'pictureSchema' }]
}

var pictureSchema = new Schema({
name : {type:String},
url : {type:String},
...
}
```

In photos array than you just put id of the pictures doc, when you populate the photos array it will put pictureSceham doc insted of _id.

Comment: I think that 'limit' in that case would limit the number of events returned. I'm attempting to limit the number of 'photos' within the photos array inside of each event. Trickier unfortunately.

Comment: Ups i looked to fast in your problem I'm sory for that!

Comment: Oh and In my company we always put picture in its own schema, because they hold the information independat from eventSchema. And if population fails, you can always do another find in pictureSchema and then req.send({eventDoc: {}, pictureDoc: {})

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a constantly growing array field. It's not good for performance because MongoDB (well, if <= 2.6/using mmap) will be moving the document around when it grows outside of the space allocated for it by the storage engine, causing performance problems. You should change your schema to avoid an array like this, but I can't really say more about how you should do it because I don't know much about your use case.

There is a way to limit the number of array elements returned in a find query though, using [`$slice` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "x" : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] })
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 0 }, { "x" : { "$slice" : 2 } })
{ "_id" : 0, "x" : [0, 1] }
```